# Confused between the difference between JSX.Element vs React.Component and when to use them with React-dom-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am starting out a new `react-typescript` project and I am using `react-router-dom` to manage routing but I am running into the following error in the browser counter:

`Matched leaf route at location "/restaurant" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page`

Here's the code:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
                    <SiteNav hasItemInCart={false} numberOfItemsInCart={0}/>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/home" children={Home} />
                        <Route path="/restaurant" children={Restaurant} />
                        <Route path="/hostel" children={Hostel} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>

export default class Home extends Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    Home
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
class Hostel extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Hostal">
                <body>Hostal</body>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As I understand it I am suppose to return a `JSX.element` but typescript is throwing errors when I try to use it. Why can't I use `React.Component`? How should I do this instead?

Answer (score 3):

`JSX.Element` is the type of already *rendered* JSX. For example:

```
const a: JSX.Element = <>asd</>
const b: JSX.Element = <SomeComponent />
```

`React.Component` is the type of a component that knows how to produce a `JSX.Element` when rendered with specific props.

```
function A() { return <>Testing</> } // A is a component
const a: JSX.Element = <A />
```

Typically, `children` in React is a `JSX.Element` that you pass as the contents of a tag.

```
<A>
  <div>children go here</div>
</A>
```

Or you can use the `children` prop explicitly:

```
<A children={<div>children go here</div>} />
```

---

So in your case, you are passing a component to a prop that expects rendered content.

If you want to pass in rendered content, you want either:

```
<Route path="/home" children={<Home />} />
```

Or:

```
<Route path="/home"><Home/></Route>
```

Though modern version of react router recommend passing JSX to the `element` prop. So use this unless you're on an older version.

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up React types and the `Route` component API. In `react-router-dom@6` there is now only an `element` prop (*no `component` or `render`/`children` function props*) taking a `React.ReactNode`, .a.k.a. ***any valid JSX***.

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

You are passing your routed components to the `Route` using the RRDv5 `Route` component API/syntax. Convert your routes to use the `element` prop.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <SiteNav hasItemInCart={false} numberOfItemsInCart={0} />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/restaurant" element={<Restaurant />} />
    <Route path="/hostel" element={<Hostel />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of react-router-dom is in your `package.json`?
This could be a versioning problem, on react-router-dom v6 all the routes are paired like this

```
[props.path]: [props.element]
```

That means, for example, for rendering a "hey" in a "/" path

```
<Route path="/" element={<div>Hey!</div>} />
```

In your case, you'd have to invoke for `restaurants` your `<Restaurants />` component

```
<Route path="/" element={<Restaurants />} />
```